# Get reference to Xaml object in view model

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a an object created in Xaml:

```
<Grid>
   <MyObject/>
</Grid>
```

I need someway to bind the object myObject back to a property in my view model. I dont know whether this is possible, everything ive seen so far binds properties together, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming what you want is your `ViewModel` to hold the actual visual control `MyObject` in it and your `Grid` to display it via `MVVM`.

This is possible through `ContentControl` in WPF.

Assuming your `ViewModel` has a property `MyObjectView` which holds `MyObject`...

```
   <Grid>
       <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyObjectView}" />
   </Grid>
```

Having said that you must take caution that same `MyObjectView` is not bound to any other content control as that will result in an error

> "Specified element is already the logical child of another element.
>   Disconnect it first"

And if that requirement is possible then you must excercise `ContentTemplate` option.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. It kinda breaks mvvm though.

You can attach an InvokeCommandAction to this object, and bind the CommandParameter to it via ElementBinding. Then in the callback of the command which you defined in the viewmodel, you will have a reference to this object from the CommandParameter.